# Select Random Products magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, random

I want to display random products on my homepage.
I have been using this `$collection->clear()->getSelect()->order('rand()');`.
My aim is the products should be displayed randomly on every page refresh.
But here, this happens only after i clear cache and then refresh my page.
Without cache flush, it displays same products

Answer (score 0):

**Add This Block In Home Page And Check :-**

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Random" template="product/list.phtml" num_products="12"}}
```

Comment: Tried this also, still the same issue

Comment: create any layout block for display random product ??

Comment: $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
 $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();

Comment: how to display random product in homepage ??

Comment: that another template. basically  $collection->getSelect()->orderRand(); i am using to select ramdom products

Comment: if you using layout XML files then make block `cacheable="false"`

Comment: No i am not using any xml layout

Comment: Any other way ?

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in your collection**

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

**If you are facing the cache issue, you can use in your layout file**

> cacheable="false";

Blocks can be set as non-cacheable by setting the cacheable attribute false in layout XML files. For example

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Comment: Still same issue exist. When i manually run cache clean command then only it works. Else no

Comment: cacheable="false"` for home page is bad idea. If any block of a page is cacheable false then this page become **Fully Non-cacheable**

Answer (score 0):

```
$productsCol = $this
        ->getCategory($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(3);

$productsCol->getSelect()->orderRand();

$products = $productsCol->getItems();
```

Please check with this whole code.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: this does not work, as i am having cache issue.

Comment: you can add `cacheable="false"` in your layout file.

Comment: Added this too, still did not work

Comment: Then it's not cache issue.

Comment: Then what? if i manually run cache command, new products displayed on my homepage. but when i only refresh the page, same products displayed

Comment: Then, You used cacheable="true".

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: `you can add cacheable="false"` is bad idea. If any block of a page is cacheable false then this page become **Fully Non-cacheable**

Answer (score 0):

The best idea to Ajax, On the load of this page, call a page with a POST request and return `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Random`  block content.

As Magento does calculate post request as cacheable request, So don't get any issue with the cache.

**Controller Class `RandomList.php`**

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Controller\Example;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class RandomList  extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute() 
    {
        $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
    }

}
```

layout files `{routeID}_example_randomList.xml` and code is

**And code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="MStackExchange\Magento\Block\Product\ProductList\Random" name="product.info.random.prp" as="products_random" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" />
          <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">new</argument>
                </arguments>
    </container>
</layout>
```

**Block Class**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Catalog product random items block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class Random extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    private $catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;



    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __hconstruct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,    
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
             $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
             );
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();

            $collection->setPage(1, 10);

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return ['ran_products'];
    }
    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }    
}
```

Comment: My code is ready. Can u just tell me what i need to add in my code for random products would be great

Comment: Can u help please?

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes you have done/what files you have write?

Comment: HAve created a block and called template inside that. $_productCollection = $this->getProductList($category['entity_id']) is called to get product collection. $collection->clear()->getSelect()->order('RAND()'); i am usign for random product. my issue is if i clear cache then only products get changed and not on page refresh. what can be the issue.

Comment: Did u understand ?

Comment: Do you  understand what I propose the solution for this issue?

Comment: you said something about Post request. What u mean by that?

Comment: I had suggest that you need get random block content using Ajax POST.) post means request type POST/GET/REQUEST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97669/discussion-between-nafisa-and-amit-bera).